# Does the existence of an onto mapping $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ indicate the existence of a one-one mapping $g: A \to \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This statement looks so intuitive, as the existence of an onto function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ suggests that $A$'s size is not "smaller" than $\mathbb{N}$. But how should we construct a one-one mapping from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ without using the axiom of choice?

P.S. I am skeptical about whether we can escape the axiom of choice, as many other seemingly naive theorems, for instance, any relation can be reduced to a function of the same domain, has to be proved using the AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ has an inherent well-order (viz., $\omega$), you don't need AC to construct
$$
g(a):=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(n)=a\}.
$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Exactly. For functions defined on a well-ordered set, we can always find a minimum from any subset, and AC is not needed. Thanks for reminding me.